# Running msvsmon as a service in "no authentication" mode

Tags: visual-studio-2010, debugging, visual-studio-debugging

I am trying to debug a process written in C++ that gets launched prior to user logon in a virtual machine. The VM is a member of a test domain. My dev machine is not domain-joined, so I can only use Msvsmon in *no authentication* mode.

I have often used no authentication mode successfully when running Msvsmon interactively. Now I am running it as a service, and when I try to connect from VS2010 I get a message saying:

> Unable to connect to '192.168.56.128'.  The Microsoft Visual Studio Remote Debugging Monitor is either not running on the remote machine or is running in Windows authentication mode.

How can I debug the remote process in this situation? I am open to other suggestions than running Msvsmon as a service.